# Could not find the WLServlet Jar

Tags: spring, jakarta-ee, servlets, weblogic, weblogic11g

I have below code which works fine in apache

```
@WebServlet("/myservlet")
```

When I deploy the same in weblogic it is not working. After internet search I came to know that I should use something like: `@WLServlet (name = "LoginServlet", mapping = {"/LoginServlet"})`

and I have to use this import statement `import weblogic.servlet.annotation.WLServlet;` as well.

But I don't know which jar contains these classes.. Can anyone help me to identify the jar.. I have tried Google search for it and it didn't help..

Regards,

Rinu

Comment: What weblogic version are you using? This annotation `@WLServlet` is deprecated in WLS 12 but `@WebServlet` is supported in it

Comment: Weblogic version is 10.3.6.0

Comment: Try $WL_HOME/modules/com.bea.core.weblogic.web.api_1.4.0.0.jar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @JoseK suggested,
Use $WL_HOME/modules/com.bea.core.weblogic.web.api_1.4.0.0.jar